unable to install @react-native-firebase/firestore on an expo project
knowing that all these are working corectly
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.1.2",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^19.1.2",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^19.1.2",
project dep verions:
"expo": "^50.0.14",
"react-native": "0.73.6",
this solution worked on windows and not on mac, and I'm not sure what to do.:
npm install --save @react-native-firebase/firestore --legacy-peer-deps
-----------The Error --------------------------------------
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: myAppName@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @react-native-firebase/app@19.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"19.1.2" from @react-native-firebase/auth@19.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/auth@"^19.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"19.1.2" from @react-native-firebase/crashlytics@19.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/crashlytics@"^19.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @react-native-firebase/firestore@"^19.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @react-native-firebase/app@19.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-firebase/app@"19.2.2" from @react-native-firebase/firestore@19.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore
npm ERR!     @react-native-firebase/firestore@"^19.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2024-04-15T18_52_48_112Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2024-04-15T18_52_48_112Z-debug-0.log

Please provide the errors so that the community can help you better.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
